# Play 2.3 FakeApplication mode not setting in test?

Tags: scala, testing, scalatest

I'm using play 2.3.8 and have some configuration in my GlobalSettings that change based on the mode of the application. So I have something like this:

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {
    override def onLoadConfig(config: Configuration, path: java.io.File, classloader: ClassLoader, mode: Mode.Mode) = {
        println(mode)
        val customConfig = //Based on mode.*
        config ++ configuration ++ Configuration(ConfigFactory.parseMap(customConfig))
    }
}
```

And then am trying to write tests to ensure that this behavior works:

```
class MyTest extends PlaySpec {

    val testApp = FakeApplication(
        additionalConfiguration = Map(
            //SomeSettings And Stuff
            "logger.application" -> "WARN",
            "logger.root" -> "WARN"
        )
    )

    val devApp = new FakeApplication(
        additionalConfiguration = Map(
            //SomeSettings And Stuff
            "logger.application" -> "WARN",
            "logger.root" -> "WARN"
        )
    ) {
        override val mode = Mode.Dev
    }

    val prodApp = new FakeApplication(
        additionalConfiguration = Map(
            //SomeSettings And Stuff
            "logger.application" -> "WARN",
            "logger.root" -> "WARN"
        )
    ) {
        override val mode = Mode.Prod
    }

    "ThisNonWorkingTestOfMine" must {

        "when running application in test mode have config.thing = false" in running(testApp) {
            assertResult(Mode.Test)(testApp.mode)
            assertResult(false)(testApp.configuration.getBoolean("config.thing").get)
        }

        "when running application in dev mode have config.thing = false" in running(devApp) {
            assertResult(Mode.Dev)(devApp.mode)
            assertResult(false)(devApp.configuration.getBoolean("config.thing").get)
        }

        "when running application in prod mode have config.thing = true" in running(prodApp) {
            assertResult(Mode.Prod)(prodApp.mode)
            assertResult(true)(prodApp.configuration.getBoolean("config.thing").get)
        }
    }

}
```

And when I run these tests I see something a bit odd from my handy `println`:

```
Test
null
null
[info] MyTest:
[info] ThisNonWorkingTestOfMine
[info] play - Starting application default Akka system.
[info] play - Shutdown application default Akka system.
[info] - must when running application in test mode have config.thing = false
[info] play - Application started (Dev)
[info] - must when running application in dev mode have config.thing = false
[info] play - Application started (Prod)
[info] - must when running application in prod mode have config.thing = true *** FAILED ***
[info]   Expected true, but got false (MyTest.scala:64)
[info] ScalaTest
```

How do I properly set the mode of the FakeApplication in Play 2.3? The way I have it now is based on a page from [Mastering Play](https://books.google.com/books?id=OJ-9CQAAQBAJ&pg=PA186&lpg=PA186&dq=run%20FakeApplication%20prod&source=bl&ots=50VNo-CVzW&sig=pIDZoJPqXDXgy55UTPfO0e-vYhY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_msKX6KTLAhUsu4MKHaCHDQ4Q6AEIMDAD#v=onepage&q=run%20FakeApplication%20prod&f=false) but clearly that isn't the way to go when using onLoadConfig it seems

**Edit**:
I'm also experimenting with `OneAppPerTest` and creating the `FakeApplication` in the `newAppForTest` method but it's still behaving oddly, with null's like the method above. This is really strange because if I set a random property like `"foo" -> "bar"` in the `additionalConfiguration` map when making my `FakeApplication` and then try to read it from `config.getString` in my `Global` object, it get's logged as `None` even though if I do `app.configuration.getString` in the test itself it shows `bar`. It feels like there is some type of disconnect here. And I don't get null for the mode if I use the `FakeApplication.apply` method rather than `new FakeApplication`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think this has something to do with [the way that FakeApplication sets the mode to `Mode.Test` via override](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/play-test/src/main/scala/play/api/test/Fakes.scala#L220) because if I copy the FakeApplication class and remove that line and create my own version of the class that let's me set the mode I have no issues. In other words, in my tests package I declare the following class:

```
package play.api.test

import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.json.JsValue
import scala.concurrent.Future
import xml.NodeSeq
import play.core.Router
import scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction
import play.api.libs.Files.TemporaryFile
import play.api.{ Application, WithDefaultConfiguration, WithDefaultGlobal, WithDefaultPlugins }

case class FakeModeApplication(
    override val path: java.io.File = new java.io.File("."),
    override val classloader: ClassLoader = classOf[FakeModeApplication].getClassLoader,
    val additionalPlugins: Seq[String] = Nil,
    val withoutPlugins: Seq[String] = Nil,
    val additionalConfiguration: Map[String, _ <: Any] = Map.empty,
    val withGlobal: Option[play.api.GlobalSettings] = None,
    val withRoutes: PartialFunction[(String, String), Handler] = PartialFunction.empty,
    val mode: play.api.Mode.Value
) extends {
    override val sources = None
} with Application with WithDefaultConfiguration with WithDefaultGlobal with WithDefaultPlugins {
    override def pluginClasses = {
        additionalPlugins ++ super.pluginClasses.diff(withoutPlugins)
    }

    override def configuration = {
        super.configuration ++ play.api.Configuration.from(additionalConfiguration)
    }

    override lazy val global = withGlobal.getOrElse(super.global)

    override lazy val routes: Option[Router.Routes] = {
        val parentRoutes = loadRoutes
        Some(new Router.Routes() {
            def documentation = parentRoutes.map(_.documentation).getOrElse(Nil)
            // Use withRoutes first, then delegate to the parentRoutes if no route is defined
            val routes = new AbstractPartialFunction[RequestHeader, Handler] {
                override def applyOrElse[A <: RequestHeader, B >: Handler](rh: A, default: A => B) =
                    withRoutes.applyOrElse((rh.method, rh.path), (_: (String, String)) => default(rh))
                def isDefinedAt(rh: RequestHeader) = withRoutes.isDefinedAt((rh.method, rh.path))
            } orElse new AbstractPartialFunction[RequestHeader, Handler] {
                override def applyOrElse[A <: RequestHeader, B >: Handler](rh: A, default: A => B) =
                    parentRoutes.map(_.routes.applyOrElse(rh, default)).getOrElse(default(rh))
                def isDefinedAt(x: RequestHeader) = parentRoutes.map(_.routes.isDefinedAt(x)).getOrElse(false)
            }
            def setPrefix(prefix: String) {
                parentRoutes.foreach(_.setPrefix(prefix))
            }
            def prefix = parentRoutes.map(_.prefix).getOrElse("")
        })
    }
}
```

And then in my test I can use it like so:

```
val devApp = new FakeModeApplication(
    additionalConfiguration = Map(
        //SomeSettings And Stuff
        "logger.application" -> "WARN",
        "logger.root" -> "WARN"
    ), mode = Mode.Dev
)
```

And then the mode value comes through as what I set it to and not as `null`.

I'm posting this as an answer because it does solve the issue I'm facing, but I don't have an understanding of *why* the new keyword when making a FakeApplication like so: `new FakeApplication() { override mode ... }` causes the mode to come through as null in the `onLoadConfig` method on GlobalSettings. This feels like a hack rather than a solution and I'd appreciate if anyone with enough knowledge around this could post a solution that involves not copying the full FakeApplication class and changing one line.